# Is apache php single threaded?

Tags: php, apache

I got really confused.

I have an amazon virtual linux box (ec2) and runs apache and php 55 on.

What I found is this:

1. On page A I use file_get_contents to download some file from an external url. Sometimes this operation may take a while.
2. When the operation takes a while, if I try to open my site from a different browser, I can see that the page (doesn't depend on previous operation and just an normal index.php page) will be hanging until my previous operation finish.

For me, it seems suggesting that my apache and php is running a single threaded mode? I just don't think this can be a right conclusion?an If it is somehow single threaded, what can I do to improve my situation?

Comment: Stab into the dark with that duplicate. Update your question with new insights if that's not it.